# Colored Button in google appsscript

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

How i can change the color of a button which is in a personalized sidebar?

this is my html files and i don't know how i can change the color of each button, i have the color code of each color that i want

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top"> 

  </head>

  <body>
    Hello, dear I-Care's member!<br/><br/>
    Ajouter des jours Inexistants!<br/>
    <input type="button" value="Inexistants" onclick="google.script.run.JoursInexistants()" /><br/><br/>
    Ajouter des jours Mensuel!<br/>   
    <input type="button" value="Mensuel" onclick="google.script.run.JoursMensuel()" /><br/><br/>
    Ajouter des jours Férié!<br/>    
    <input type="button" value="Férié" onclick="google.script.run.JoursFerie()" /><br/><br/>
    Ajouter des jours de Congé!<br/>    
    <input type="button" value="Congé" onclick="google.script.run.JoursConge()" /><br/><br/>
    Ajouter des jours Possible!<br/>    
    <input type="button" value="Possible" onclick="google.script.run.JoursPossible()" /><br/><br/>
    Ajouter des jours en Plus!<br/>    
    <input type="button" value="Plus" onclick="google.script.run.JoursEnPlus()"/><br/><br/>
    Ajouter des jours Weekend!<br/>    
    <input type="button" value="Weekend" onclick="google.script.run.JoursWeekend()" /><br/><br/>
    Remettre à zéro!<br/>    
    <input type="button" value="Blanc" onclick="google.script.run.JoursBlanc()" /><br/><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
    <button class="share">Share</button>
    <button>Close</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you edit the HTML ?  add classes for example ? or you just have access to the CSS ?

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use CSS to color your buttons.

Assuming you put a class on each button named by the color you want.

```html
<input type="button" class="red" value="Inexistants" onclick="google.script.run.JoursInexistants()" />
    <p>Ajouter des jours Mensuel!</p> 
<input type="button" class="blue" value="Mensuel" onclick="google.script.run.JoursMensuel()" />
    <p>Ajouter des jours Férié!</p>    
<input type="button" class="yellow" value="Férié" onclick="google.script.run.JoursFerie()" />
    <p>Ajouter des jours de Congé!</p>    

...
```

```css
input {
    display: block;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

You could also make some other improvements with CSS. For exemple I put `display: block` and `<p></p>` instead of a lot of `<br/>`.

You could as well use the `<for></for>` instead of `<p></p>` in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Use [inline CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) to specify the [background-color](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp).

```
<input style="background-color:#4CAF50" type="button" value="Inexistants" onclick="google.script.run.JoursInexistants()" />
```

You could also consider some other ways for specifying styles, which may be more helpful if you want multiple buttons to have the same color, for example. (This is, in fact, highly recommended. However, it is not required, especially if you're not very familiar with the concepts. Sometimes it's best just to get it looking the way you want, and then make it "correct".)

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

I think you also need to move the link tag at the very top of your document to within the `<head></head>` tags, as shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    Hello, dear I-Care's member!<br/><br/>
    Ajouter des jours Inexistants!<br/>
    <input type="button" value="Inexistants" onclick="google.script.run.JoursInexistants()" /><br/><br/>
    Ajouter des jours Mensuel!<br/>   
    <input type="button" value="Mensuel" onclick="google.script.run.JoursMensuel()" /><br/><br/>
    Ajouter des jours Férié!<br/>    
    <input type="button" value="Férié" onclick="google.script.run.JoursFerie()" /><br/><br/>
    Ajouter des jours de Congé!<br/>    
    <input type="button" value="Congé" onclick="google.script.run.JoursConge()" /><br/><br/>
    Ajouter des jours Possible!<br/>    
    <input type="button" value="Possible" onclick="google.script.run.JoursPossible()" /><br/><br/>
    Ajouter des jours en Plus!<br/>    
    <input type="button" value="Plus" onclick="google.script.run.JoursEnPlus()"/><br/><br/>
    Ajouter des jours Weekend!<br/>    
    <input type="button" value="Weekend" onclick="google.script.run.JoursWeekend()" /><br/><br/>
    Remettre à zéro!<br/>    
    <input type="button" value="Blanc" onclick="google.script.run.JoursBlanc()" /><br/><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
    <button class="share">Share</button>
    <button>Close</button>
  </body>
</html>
```